# How to use wildcard in 'win_stat' module in Ansible?

Tags: windows, wildcards, ansible, string

I created below Ansible script where I check if a directory is present or not with wildcard but it failed for me:

```yaml
- host: windows

  vars:

    dir: 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite*' # without * playbook working well

  tasks:

    - name : check dir
      win_stat:
        path: "{{ dir }}"
      register: dirdata

    - name: check
      fail:
        msg: not present
      when: dirdata.stat.exists == false
```

Getting below error :

```
    FAILED: => { " argument for the path is of type System.String and we were unable to convert to path: Illaegel characters in path.”}
```

Can anyone suggest me for same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the Ansible Control Node can not expand a path on a Remote Node without having made a connection and lookup on it. So it is the expected behavior.

There are modules for using with wildcards like [fileglob lookup – list files matching a pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html), but

> *Matching is against local system files on the Ansible controller. To iterate a list of files on a remote node, use the [`ansible.builtin.find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-find-module) module.*

in your case [`win_find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_find_module.html) to

> *return a list of files based on specific criteria*.